# Video too large for mobile browser

Tags: html, css

I have a video on one of my html pages, and I love the dimensions for it on desktop, but on mobile its way too large, and is extending the screen.
I know this is fixable but I'm a bit confused in the solution I've looked a few up and am still confused.

```
<video width="900" height="450" autoplay loop controls >
 <source src="images/Demo.mov" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: What is the solution you looked up? You only provided the HTML. What did you try to fix this?

Comment: in which way it is extending your screen horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @PrakashRajotiya Its extending my screen horizontally to the right.

Answer (score 2):

```css
video{
  max-width:900px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<video  height="450" autoplay loop controls >
 <source src="images/Demo.mov" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

below CSS might help you.

```
video{
  max-width:900px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I implemented this but no change occurred.

Comment: @NoahSmiley remove width attribute from video.

Comment: Okay I did, I still see no change on mobile.

Comment: @NoahSmiley Maybe other CSS overriding your CSS. I have created a demo in my updated answer. please have a look.

Comment: I copied this and no change took place on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `width` and `height` attributes inside the HTML.

   ```html
   <video autoplay loop controls >
    <source src="images/Demo.mov" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
   ```
2. Use [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to style the video frame. Example:

   ```css
   @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     video {
       width: 900px;
       height: 450px;
     }
   }
   ```

See the first line of the CSS code. There stands `max-width: 600px`. This is the maximal width of your screen. 600px are small devices.

**Disclaimer:** the CSS code is pseudo code. Play with the numbers to fit it into your screen and for mobile use percentage instead of pixels.

If you use `width: 100%;` it will be responsive to any screen size.

Using the CSS code multiple times with other screen sizes, you could support tablet or computer screens.

**P.S.:** Use mp4 files instead of mov files. It's more widely supported by the browsers.

Comment: how do I specify within the css that its desktop or mobile?

Comment: I implemented this, and pasted what you wrote in my CSS file, but the video increased in size on both the mobile and desktop.

Comment: @NoahSmiley please read the disclaimer. You've to play with the numbers. And use it different times for wider screen sizes.

Comment: I did, even after manipulating the values there was still no change.

Comment: @NoahSmiley I've also added a link. There you find some more documentation about media queries. It's indeed not the easiest thing of CSS. That's why I'm using Bootstrap 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226314/discussion-between-h-pauwelyn-and-noahsmiley).